# How to get nth bit (from right) in a binary equivalent of an integer in PHP?

Tags: php, binary, numbers

Suppose I want to find 2nd bit in binary equivalent of 13 (binary : 1101). It should return 0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

```
($x >> 1) & 1
```

Comment: And function to get nth bit:

function nbit($number, $n) { return ($number >> $n-1) & 1;}

Comment: @stereofrog: you're right, but for nth bit, you've to find out pow(2, n-1) which is again done by shifting.

Comment: And if you don't know what is the last bit set to 1 of a $number variable, then you can do:
`function getLeftMost1Bit($number) { return log($number)/log(2); }`

Answer (score 7):

Nice answer by [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643722/how-to-get-nth-bit-from-right-in-a-binary-equivalent-of-an-integer-in-php/2643735#2643735), definitely go with his solution. Here's another way to do it though, using string manipulation (I know, I know...):

```
substr(decbin($x), -2, 1)
```

Comment: holy sh.. that's even more difficult to read then bit shifts. However very original way of doing this.

Comment: @Pim Lol, thanks. Logically it's pretty straight forward though, maybe too much so. ;)

Comment: What is done virtually in bit shifting is done physically in string manipulation! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a bit more universal function to extract also bit ranges.

```
function extract_bits($value, $start_pos, $end_pos)
{
    $mask = (1 << ($end_pos - $start_pos)) - 1;
    return ($value >> $start_pos) & $mask;
}
```

for example to extract value of the second bit from 13 it'd be:

```
extract_bits(13,1,2);
```